# Python 3.6 pyinstaller WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, python-3.6, pyinstaller

Windows 10 стоит Python 3.6.7. Собираю проект pyinstaller-ом, проект собирается, но с

```
WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
```

на компе где собираю могу запустить, а на другом выдает ошибку что вышеуказанная api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll не найдена. Изначально выдавал намного больше WARNING-ов, их исправил добавлением

```
--paths C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_50c6cb8431e7428f
```

Странно что даже пустой код выдает ту же ошибку. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить путь на `C:\Windows\System32\downlevel\`, там те же файлы + отсутствующий.